# operator definition in base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following sample code. class `bar` is derived from the base class `foo` and allocates memory for `ptr_x` while read/write access are granted through the base class. This is a toy model for a large code in which read/write functions are the same for all different variants of an object but memory allocation slightly differs in different variants.

```
#include <iostream>

class foo{
protected:
    int *ptr_x;

public:
    foo(){
        std::cout << " 1) Inside foo constructor: " << ptr_x << std::endl;
    }

    void read() 
    {
        std::cout << " 2) Inside read function: " <<  ptr_x << std::endl;    
        std::cout << " 3) Inside read function: " << *ptr_x << std::endl;
    }
    void operator=(const int rhs)
    {
        std::cout << " 4) Inside operator= : " <<  ptr_x << std::endl;
        *ptr_x = rhs;
    }        
};
class bar: public foo{

public:
    bar(int a)
    : foo()
    {
        std::cout << " 5) Inside bar constructor: " << ptr_x << std::endl;
        ptr_x = new int;
        std::cout << " 6) Inside bar constructor: " << ptr_x << std::endl;
        *ptr_x = a;
    }
    ~bar()
    {
        std::cout << " 7) Inside bar destructor: " << ptr_x << std::endl;
        if (ptr_x != NULL) {delete ptr_x; ptr_x = NULL;}
    }
};
int main (){
    bar a(20);
    a.read();
    a = 40;
    a.read();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, I get:

```
 1) Inside foo constructor: 0
 5) Inside bar constructor: 0
 6) Inside bar constructor: 0x1d8f010
 2) Inside read function: 0x1d8f010
 3) Inside read function: 20
 1) Inside foo constructor: 0x7f40c11e3b68
 5) Inside bar constructor: 0x7f40c11e3b68
 6) Inside bar constructor: 0x1d8f030
 7) Inside bar destructor: 0x1d8f030
 2) Inside read function: 0x1d8f030
 3) Inside read function: 0
 7) Inside bar destructor: 0x1d8f030
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001d8f030 ***
```

I have the following questions: 1) Why does not code enter `operator=` in the base class? 2) Why is there a second call made to the constructor/destructor ? 3) why is there a `double free` problem?

what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Ok `double free` problem is obvious, but why is there two instances of same memory locations? This somehow has to do with `operator=` since when I comment it out everything is fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reasoning for the observed behavior:**

The compiler uses the conversion constructor in derived class,

```
  bar(int a)
```

for evaluating:

```
  a = 40;
```

It takes in the integer `40` and creates a `bar` object using the conversion constructor and then assigns the created `bar` object to `a` using the implicit copy assignment operator(`=`) generated by the compiler for class `bar`.

This is the reason you see additional calls to `bar` constructor and that Base class overloaded `=` is never called. Also, the reason for double free lies in here, You have multiple `bar` objects which keep pointing to the dynamic memory allocated for `ptr_x` and when one of the object goes out of scope the destructor is called which deallocates the memory but leaves the other objects member pointer in a dangling state.

**How to solve these problems:**
You should mark the conversion constructor **[explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)** if you don't want the compiler to use it for implicit conversions like this.

You should follow the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)** for your class `bar`.

**Caveat:**
Note that the `=` operator in the base classes is always hidden by the implicitly generated `=` operator for the derived class.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean I always have to define the `=` operator for derived classes? What are operators are like this?

Comment: @GradGuy: If you don't redefine the `=` operator for your derived class the compiler implicitly generates it thus hiding the base class `=`. Read more about [Function Hiding](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9), that should give you a good idea of where the same situation will apply.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question you should have declared
 `bar (int a)` as

```
explicit bar(int a).
```

this gives a proper compilation error that class bar should have `=` operator defined.